# HCE support for ISO/IEC 14443-3 Type B?

Tags: android, nfc, hce

The Android's developer guide states that "Support for Nfc-B is optional".

I cannot find any more information about Type B HCE.

So is it possible to enable Type B support on Android devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an app developer perspective you should(*) not really care which underlying protocol is used. The application layer protocol (ISO/IEC 7816-4) is the same for ISO/IEC 14443 Type A and Type B.

Looking at devices in the field, some devices use Type A for HCE and some seem to use Type B. So it's basically the device manufacturer who decides if Type A or Type B is used. The Android API provides no means for the app developer to influence this.

*) I'm well aware that this means that the reader side needs to take care about handling both protocols and that this may be problematic when you try to integrate with legacy infrastructure.

Comment: What I'm facing is that the specific reader side support Type B only, which obviously requires Type B HCE. As you suggested, it is the manufacturer who decides this, so would you please give any example which uses Type B for HCE? Thanks!